# Getting error 'variant constructor can't be found' while compiling

Tags: reason, bucklescript, reason-react

I was trying out use a sortable list component *([react-sortable-hoc](https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc))* on a ReasonReact project. But I ran into an error which I was trying to figure out for couple of hours.

Steps I followed:

- made the @bs binds for `sortableContainer()` and `sortableElement()` for the module `react-sortable-hoc`
- faked the reactClass returned by the both functions and put it under file `SortableContainer.js` and `SortableElement.js`
- Made an another React component called Todolist which use the component SortableContainer, and SortableContainer use the component SortableElement.

**Code Snippet**

```
/* SortableContainer.re */

[@bs.val] [@bs.module "react-sortable-hoc"] external sortableContainer : 'a =>
ReasonReact.reactClass = "";

let sortableContainerReactClass: ReasonReact.reactClass = sortableContainer(() => {
  (ReasonReact.createElement(SortableElement))
});

let make = (children) =>
  ReasonReact.wrapJsForReason(
    ~reactClass=sortableContainerReactClass,
    ~props = { "onSortEnd": () => {} },
    children
  );
```

```
/* SortableElement.re */

[@bs.val] [@bs.module "react-sortable-hoc"] external sortableElement : 'a => 
ReasonReact.reactClass = "";

let sortableElementReactClass: ReasonReact.reactClass = sortableElement(() => {
  (ReasonReact.stringToElement("testing is good"))
});

let make = (children) =>
ReasonReact.wrapJsForReason(
  ~reactClass=sortableElementReactClass,
  ~props = { "onSortEnd": () => {} },
  children
);
```

```
/* List.re */

let component = ReasonReact.statelessComponent("List");


let make = (~items=[||], _children) => {
  {
    ...component,
    render: (_self) => {
      
        
      
    }
  }
};
```

When I compile this code I get this error.

```
# ERROR

We've found a bug for you!
  /Users/jaisonjustus/code/todotabre/src/components/SortableContainer.re 5:34-48

  3 │
  4 │ let sortableContainerReactClass: ReasonReact.reactClass = sortableConta
      iner(() => {
  5 │   (ReasonReact.createElement(SortableElement))
  6 │ });
  7 │

  The variant constructor SortableElement can't be found.

  - If it's defined in another module or file, bring it into scope by:
    - Annotating it with said module name: let food = MyModule.Apple
    - Or specifying its type: let food: MyModule.fruit = Apple
  - Constructors and modules are both capitalized. Did you want the latter?
    Then instead of let foo = Bar, try module Foo = Bar.
```

What's wrong in this code?

Comment: `SortableElement` is a module. What about `SortableElement.make(~children=[], ())` instead of `ReasonReact.createElement(SortableElement)`?

Comment: @noziar SortableElement.make(~children=[], ()) is giving me and error `This function has type
    'a =>
    ReasonReact.component(ReasonReact.stateless, ReasonReact.noRetainedProps,
                           ReasonReact.actionless)
  It only accepts 1 argument; here, it's called with more.`

Comment: True, your `make` function only has one argument. `SortableElement.make([])`?